# use T.parameter when passing list of class ex:(List<User>) to a method

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am using "search_widget" package in my project in different screens so I built a method that take a list of class:

```
search<T>(List<T> myList, context) {
  return SearchWidget<T>(
    dataList: myList,
    hideSearchBoxWhenItemSelected: false,
    listContainerHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4,
    queryBuilder: (query, myList) {
      return myList
          .where(
              (item) => **myList.name**toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
    },
    popupListItemBuilder: (T myList) {
      return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12),
        child: Text(
          **myList.name**,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
        ),
      );
    },
    selectedItemBuilder: (T t, VoidCallback deleteSelectedItem) {
      //TODO: navigate here to user profile
      return null;
    },
    // widget customization
    noItemsFoundWidget: Center(
      child: Text("No item Found"),
    ),
    textFieldBuilder: (TextEditingController controller, FocusNode focusNode) {
      return SearchTextField(controller, focusNode);
    },
  );
}
```

and I can use the search method like that.

```
class AllEmployeeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  List<Employee> employee;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return search(employee, context);
  }
}
```

assuming that I have data from Firestore inside my list.

the problem is when I use myList.name it says "The getter 'name' isn't defined for the class 'List<'T'>'. "

shouldn't it give that error only when I pass List<'Employee'> to search method without 'name' parameter into it?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means you are trying to access the `name` on a List of data, which is not there. check this code in `search` method:

```dart
 return myList
          .where(
              (item) => myList.name.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
```

As you can see, `myList.name` is giving you this error.

Since `where` is giving you a reference name for an object in the list as `item` the code should be:

```
 return myList
          .where(
              (item) => item.name.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))
          .toList();
```

This should resolve your error.

**On an additional note**:
Type generic methods work best when you provide the type of data you are going to perform a set of operations on. But that also means that the code you are writing in that method should work for all the possible `Data types` denoted by `T`.

In this case `search()` is specific to the `User` type of object. In this case, you should not use type generics at all.

A good example of type Generics would be:

```dart
bool isEmpty<T extends Iterable>(T dataCollection){
  return dataCollection == null || dataCollection.isEmpty;
}
```

As you can see, in this example we use generics to allow all types of collections which are subclasses of `Iterable` class.

While this allows us support to a range of data types, it also makes sure that the passed data type is supported or not on compile time.